# C++ : memory leak for just constructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am creating a class from a huge external package.
And I ran:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo("bar", 100);
if(!foo)
{
    delete foo;
}
```

with

```
Foo::Foo(TString bar, int num)
{
    setnull();
}
```

and the setnull() is just setting every class pointers in NULL, like:

```
void Foo::setnull()
{
    fooArray = NULL
    ...
}
```

and the destructor

```
Foo::~Foo()
{
    if(fooArray != NULL)
            delete[] fooArray;
    ...
    setnull();
}
```

There are actually a lot of pointers to the classes from the external packages setting to NULL as well in the .hh file. As a result I got:

```
definitely lost: 332 bytes in 1 blocks
```

I also get indirect lost from adding in constructor:

```
fooArray = new (nothrow) bool [5];
    if (fooArray == NULL)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: memory could not be allocated"<<endl;
    }
fooArray[0] = 0;
```

with

```
indirectly lost: 26 bytes in 2 blocks
```

(one other thing, somehow the title for Stackoverflow tends to eat up the "++" sign)

Comment: Why the obsession with pointers? Pointers are generally an **inferior** solution.

Comment: Is it? I would consider that.

Comment: @BeTheSame well, you made an attempt to use a pointer and you immediately created a memory leak. Any solution that lets you do that should be treated with care :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Foo* foo = new Foo("bar", 100);
if(!foo)
{
    delete foo;
}
```

You're only deleting `foo` if it's `NULL`, if `new` returns an object, you won't delete it.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointer out in other answers, this logic is wrong:

```
if(!foo)
{
    delete foo;
}
```

But you don't have to perform the check anyway: calling delete in a null pointer is a no-op and completely safe. So you could simplify your code to

```
Foo* foo = new Foo("bar", 100);
delete foo;
```

Of course, the simpler, safer option would be

```
Foo foo("bar", 100);
```